# Dell laptop with two external screens

Tags: gnu-screen, multi-monitor

I have a laptop with Linux Mint Mate and this board graphic: Nvidia-G98M - Frame NVS 160M. I am trying to connect one screen Dell Inc. 15", through the VGA cable, and a Screen Asus 22" through DVI. On the menu "Configure Preferences" I can see all screens, but when I active all only two screens turn on with image.

At the moment I can only use the 15" and 22" screens. The screen of the laptop appears with option off and doesn't show any image. If I choose turn on the screen laptop and press the button "Apply" the normal message box doesn't appear, and the image on the screen Laptop doesn't appear.

On Driver Manager I choose this option:
[image]

How can I fix this problem?
Note: I've already chosen the first option but the result it is the same.
Thanks